# How to create multiple eclipse view in same perspective..?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I created a eclipse view plugin .
i want to make multiple instance of this view in the same perspective.
i do some search and i find that for make multiple instance of any view i have to set

```
allowMultiple="true"
```

in `plugin.xml by using the org.eclipse.ui.views extension point`

but its  not working ..

so what is the way to create multiple view instance.

thanks

Comment: Do you want to add them initially (by code or configuration) or can the user open it multiple times? Please add the code/configuration how you add the view instances.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the same view multiple times in the same perspective, you must specify a "secondary id" for each of the views. How you interpret this id is up to you. For a specific view id, everything from the first colon (:) is considered the secondary id. E.g. "org.eclipse.ui.views.ProgressView:go home" is split into view ID="org.eclipse.ui.views.ProgressView" and secondary ID="go home"...

Answer (score 0):

if you mean something like class editor in eclipse, you have to add org.eclipse.ui.editors extension point in plugin.xml, and your class should extends from org.eclipse.ui.part.EditorPart. See it[(click)](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseEditors/article.html).

Comment: sry but i think i clearly mention that i have eclipse view plugin ..
not any editor an all... and i also mention that we have to add some thing   `allowMultiple="true"` in org.eclipse.ui.views extension point.. 
can  u plz read my question again.. thanks